# Zend Framework3 similar routes conflict

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework3

I'm using ZF3, in *module.config.php* file in Post module, I have one of these two routes,

```
'create-post' => [
    'type' => Literal::class,
    'options' => [
        // Change this to something specific to your module
        'route' => '/post/create',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\PostController::class,
            'action' => 'create',
        ]
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [
        // You can place additional routes that match under the
        // route defined above here.
    ],
],

'post' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        // Change this to something specific to your module
        'route' => '/post[/:postId]',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\PostController::class,
            'action' => 'show',
        ],
        'constraints' => array(
            'postId' => '\d{4}'
        )
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [
        // You can place additional routes that match under the
        // route defined above here.
    ],
]
```

Now when I visit *http://localhost:8080/post/create* it works, but when I visit *http://localhost:8080/post/32*, it doesn't work. It say 404 error, page not found.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The ID has to be 4 digits, no?

Comment: No, it can be any number with 4 digits

Comment: How is that different from what I said? http://localhost:8080/post/32 isn't 4 digits, it's 2, so won't match?

Comment: I mean max 4 digits

Comment: it's working now, I changed it to 2

Comment: If you wanted it between 1 and 4 digits (i.e. anything between 0 and 9999), `\d{1,4}` should work. Changing it to {2} just means that `5` and `123` won't work for example.

Comment: @JonStirling You are correct. I changed it in config file. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @jon Stirling comment on my question, I changed the constraints on post route and it worked.

**Changed 'postId' => '\d{4}' to** **'postId' => '\d{1,4}'**

```
'post' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/post[/:postId]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\PostController::class,
                        'action'        => 'show',
                    ],
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'postId' => '\d{1,4}'
                    )
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    // You can place additional routes that match under the
                    // route defined above here.
                ],
            ]
```

Comment: As an aside, as you want to use ID's, why did you change it from literally every example which uses `[0-9]+` (any amount of characters 0 to 9). Also, why do you not use the `child_routes` for different actions? (e.g. `showAction` on `/post` route and `addAction` on `/create` child route)

Comment: I face some issue with child routes, thats why I'm not using it. For ex: I have a route /post/33 with name 'post', and it's child route name 'edit', so it will become /post/33/edit, now how can I call 'edit' from view using any helper. I tried 'url' helper like $this->url('edit') in href of anchor tag, but it says 'Route with name "edit" not found' ?!!

Comment: If you got `post` (route `/post`), child `view` (route `/:id`) and child of that `edit` (route `/edit`), the full route **NAME** for the edit route is `post/view/edit`, where the `view` name expects an ID. So the `url` view helper should be: `$this->url('post/view/edit', ['id' => $id])`. Viewing a route would be `$this->url('post/view', ['id' => $id])` and the plain index page would be `$this->url('post')` (no params there). If you'd like I can post you an example.